# Android: associating a new file suffix with an existing MIME type?

Tags: android, mapping, mime-types, suffix

I asked a similar question in the Android Enthusiasts stackexchange forum, but no answer has been offered. I'm posting this question here, in hopes that possibly more people will see it and perhaps supply an answer.

This is the Android Enthusiasts post:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203123/oreo-associating-an-app-with-all-files-with-a-given-extension

In summary, I am looking for a way to tell my Oreo-based Android system to associate a new suffix with the `text/plain` MIME type. In other words, suppose that I want all files on my device with the suffix `.abc` to be considered to be `text/plain`. I want this to be a system-wide mapping, not just a mapping for a particular app.

To be clear, I am ***not*** simply looking for a way to associate an app with `text/plain`. What I ***am*** looking for is a way to cause all files with this `.abc` suffix to ***always*** be considered to be `text/plain` on my device.

I know that there are some suffix-to-mime-type mappings under Android. For example. `.txt` is always mapped to `text/plain`, as is `.log` and a number of other suffixes. So at least theoretically, it should be possible to map any suffix (such as my `.abc` example) to `text/plain`. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

There is a file called `/system/lib/content-types.properties` which seems to offer this capability (see below for a listing of that file from my device). However, when I put `abc=text/plain` into that file, items with an `.abc` suffix are still not recognized as `text/plain`, even after a reboot.

I'm running a rooted device with Xposed and Magisk, and so I can install unoffical modules. However, I haven't found any Xposed or Magisk modules which offer this capability. I am also able to run custom `init.d` scripts, in case there might be some way to enable this capability in that manner.

Can anyone suggest any way I can accomplish what I want?  Thank you very much.

Here are the contents of my `/system/lib/content-types.properties` file ...

```
# If you want to support more recognized mimetypes in libcore.net.MimeUtils, add them here

docm=application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12
xlsb=application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12
xlsm=application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12
ppsm=application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12
ppsx=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
pptm=application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12

asm=text/x-asm
cc=text/x-c
conf=text/plain
cpp=text/x-c
css=text/css
c=text/x-c
cxx=text/x-c
def=text/plain
dic=text/x-c
f77=text/x-fortran
f90=text/x-fortran
for=text/x-fortran
f=text/x-fortran
hh=text/x-c
hpp=text/x-c
h=text/x-c
ics=text/calendar
ifb=text/calendar
in=text/plain
jad=text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
java=text/x-java-source
ksh=text/plain
list=text/plain
log=text/plain
pas=text/x-pascal
pl=text/plain
properties=|
prop=text/plain
p=text/x-pascal
py=text/x-python
rc=text/plain
sgml=text/sgml
sgm=text/sgml
s=text/x-asm
vcs=text/x-vcalendar
```